# Open DB connection from an IntentService Constructor

Tags: android, sqlite, service

When trying to open up a DB connection via the normal mechanism a `nullpointerexecption` is thrown at the point `dbhelper.getWritableDatabase`.

The problem seems to stem from the `IntentService` context I am passing in.

```
    public AnalysisService() {
    super("AnalysisService");
    Log.d("ANALYSIS_SERVICE", "Service started");
    try{
    db = new DBAdapter(this)
    db.openDB();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("ANALYSIS_SERVICE", Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        Log.e("ANALYSIS_SERVICE", e.toString());
    }
}
```

The `db.open` method is executed here:

```
public class DBAdapter implements Database {

protected Context context;
protected SQLiteDatabase db;
private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

public DBAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    Log.e("DB_ADAPTER", "CREATED");
}

/**
 * Opens a database connection.
 * @return
 * @throws SQLException
 */
@Override
public DBAdapter openDB() throws SQLException {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); //NULLP EXCEPTION THROWN HERE
    return this;
}
```

And if it helps the constructor for the `dbHelper` is:

```
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    Log.e("DB_HELPER", "created");
}
```

This has been puzzling me for the last day or so I can't understand why the context is invalid. Also I have logged all the constructors and all the objects are being created correctly, so it is not the case that DBHelper is null.

As well as using the context as this, I have also tried using `getBaseContext()` and `getApplicationContext()`, both resulting in the same error.

From the debug printing the stack trace, I get:

```
    11-21 13:23:45.419: D/ANALYSIS_SERVICE(3930): 
[android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221), 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:166), 
com.emotifi.database.DBAdapter.openDB(DBAdapter.java:42), 
com.emotifi.analysis.AnalysisService.<init>(AnalysisService.java:45),
 java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method), 
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319), 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2234), 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:123), 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201), 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99), 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137), 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424), 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method), 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511), 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817), 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584), 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're setting the context too early in the `IntentService` lifecycle.

Override `onCreate` and set it there:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d("ANALYSIS_SERVICE", "Service started");
    db = DatabaseFactory.getDefault(this);
}
```

Then open the database connection in `onHandleIntent`:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Logging
    Log.d("ANALYSIS_SERVICE", "Intent handled");

    try {
        db.openDB();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ANALYSIS_SERVICE", "Unable to open database");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you know I was using a DatabaseFactory ? ha